# Default settings in Print Composer?

Tags: print-composer

Is it possible to change default settings for things like font for labels in Print Composer?
-TVZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that most of what you are interested in would be best managed by creating and using templates. In that case, the settings for fonts of label boxes which have been inserted in the composer will be maintained. It is worth the investment to understand templates, as they allow you to create consistent maps between projects.

In a template, if a new label is added/created it will still have the default font.

As far as I know!

Comment: The problem is, I'm doing a series of maps, where each one will have a number of text labels added. Each will be different, so I have to format each one. I guess I could just make a template w/ a bunch of formatted labels; then for each map I would just change the wording for the labels I need. Is that about the best way to do this?

Comment: Too bad there's not a way to copy labels (right?) (which have been formatted); then paste them & simply change the words.

Comment: Well there is......   click on the label (it will then be "in focus" with the corner handles visible), CTRL-C (in Win7) then move your mouse to roughly where you want the new label, CTRL-V, Presto! Simply change the words! Finish the alignment by hand, ideally snap to grid.

Comment: How about arrows? I'll be making a bunch of them, pointing in different directions. I want them a bit lighter & w/ a smaller head than the default. If I copy & paste, they'll be pointing the wrong way. Can I set the default for the thickness, etc., that I want?

Comment: I am in a similar situation, wherein need to set the default values for arrows. Did you found the solution?